# How can I extract the timestamp of an xts object in R?

Tags: r, xts

I am having problems accessing the timestamp of my `xts` object in R.

The structure of the object looks like this

```
                    FB.Open FB.High FB.Low FB.Close FB.Volume  FB.WAP FB.hasGaps FB.Count
2015-10-30 10:40:00  104.61  104.62 104.35   104.38      4532 104.472          0     2067
```

I have no problems accessing `FB.Open`, `FB.High`, etc.

I am doing so by calling `data[1,1]` for example and would get the following

```
                    FB.Open
2015-10-30 10:30:00  104.38
```

The problem is when I try to access the index

For example, when I do something like

```
data[1,0]
```

I would get

```
2015-10-30 10:30:00
```

I get an `xts` object with zero-width which I can't seem to manipulate.

I simply need to put the timestamp inside a variable.

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check `?index` and `?.index`

Comment: @Pascal thanks! got it. I am learning.

Comment: You should read [the xts vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/vignettes/xts.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `index`(xtsobject)

```
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')
index(sample.xts)

> index(sample.xts)
  [1] "2007-01-02 EST" "2007-01-03 EST" "2007-01-04 EST" "2007-01-05 EST" "2007-01-06 EST" "2007-01-07 EST"
  [7] "2007-01-08 EST" "2007-01-09 EST" "2007-01-10 EST" "2007-01-11 EST" "2007-01-12 EST" "2007-01-13 EST"
 [13] "2007-01-14 EST" "2007-01-15 EST" "2007-01-16 EST" "2007-01-17 EST" "2007-01-18 EST" "2007-01-19 EST"
 [19] "2007-01-20 EST" "2007-01-21 EST" "2007-01-22 EST" "2007-01-23 EST" "2007-01-24 EST" "2007-01-25 EST"
```

Comment: you need to load the package `zoo` for the `index()` function.